# How do I use javascript to correctly loop an iMacro?

Tags: imacros

This is the javascript that i have

```
for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
 {
  iimPlay("macro.iim");
 }
```

This is the macro that I have

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !TIMEOUT 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=30
```

When I start the javascript I notice that the imacro doesn't work properly. the imacro is suppose to follow people in a list and continue that. however, the javascript does not allow this. I think it's because the javascript is not following {{!LOOP}} and is starting the macro from ground 0 over and over again, someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes:

```
for (i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
 {
    iimSet("loop", i);
    iimPlay("macro.iim");
 }
```

and

```
SET !TIMEOUT 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

TAG POS={{loop}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=30
```